# Why is a 'border-bottom' looking like an ellipse on mobile?

Tags: html, css, mobile, ellipse

When I open developer tools on computer there is no issue and looks great, even when I adjust the screen size. However, when I open the link on my phone the underlined portion looks like an ellipse. I'm not sure how to fix it since I can't see this problem on my computer. The photos I am attaching it what it looks like on my computer at full size, computer reduced size, and phone screen. Here is the link to the test page + CSS: https://www.juddbuilders.com/quick-deliveries/reserve-at-chalfont/the-jordan-homesite-34-tabs.php

[Desktop Reduced](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ff0UW.jpg)

[Desktop Full](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9jFY.jpg)

[Phone screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QhQdE.jpg)

```
  /* button:focus,
  input:focus,
  textarea:focus,
  select:focus {
    outline: none; } */
  
  .tabs {
    display: block;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    -moz-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-right: 2vw;
    padding-left: 2vw;

}

.tab-slider{
    padding-top: 0;
}

.QDslider{
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-bottom:9vw;
}

.requestmore{
    height:40px;
}

    .tabs [class^="tab"] label,
    .tabs [class*=" tab"] label {
      color: #292929;
      cursor: pointer;
      display: block;
      font-size: 1.1em;
      /* font-weight: 300; */
      line-height: 1em;
      padding: 1rem 0;
      text-align: center; }
    .tabs [class^="tab"] [type="radio"],
    .tabs [class*=" tab"] [type="radio"] {
      border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(239, 237, 239, 0.5);
      cursor: pointer;
      -webkit-appearance: none;
      -moz-appearance: none;
      appearance: none;
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
      -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
      -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
      -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
      transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out; }
      .tabs [class^="tab"] [type="radio"]:hover, .tabs [class^="tab"] [type="radio"]:focus,
      .tabs [class*=" tab"] [type="radio"]:hover,
      /* .tabs [class*=" tab"] [type="radio"]:focus {
        border-bottom: 1px solid #fd264f; } */
      .tabs [class^="tab"] [type="radio"]:checked,
      .tabs [class*=" tab"] [type="radio"]:checked {
        border-bottom: 2px solid #fd264f; }
      .tabs [class^="tab"] [type="radio"]:checked + div,
      .tabs [class*=" tab"] [type="radio"]:checked + div {
        opacity: 1; }
      .tabs [class^="tab"] [type="radio"] + div,
      .tabs [class*=" tab"] [type="radio"] + div {
        display: block;
        opacity: 0;
        padding: 2rem 0;
        width: 90%;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
        -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
        transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out; }
    .tabs .tab-2 {
      width: 50%; }
      .tabs .tab-2 [type="radio"] + div {
        width: 200%;
        margin-left: 200%; }
      .tabs .tab-2 [type="radio"]:checked + div {
        margin-left: 0; }
      .tabs .tab-2:last-child [type="radio"] + div {
        margin-left: 100%; }
      .tabs .tab-2:last-child [type="radio"]:checked + div {
        margin-left: -100%; }

        @media screen and (max-width: 768px){
            .QDslider{
                margin-bottom:20vw;
            }

        }


        @media screen and (max-width: 678px){
            .QDslider{
                margin-bottom:63vw;
            }
        }
```

I tried changing the border-bottom styling in CSS, like the thickness. I also tried adding a media query for the border. The ellipses remained unchanged.

Comment: Can you show us the relevant HTML and if possible make a runnable snippet which demonstrates the problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: if you're trying to see it on iphone, you can download the simulator on mac and it'll run it on a specific device. Sometimes, especially with Safari, css can act different. WIth the simulator, you can have the safari dev tools open and adjust things in real time on the phone screen.

Comment: The simulator worked great! problem solved, thanks!!